# Memory keeps going up when a client reconnects to my TCP server

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and I'm trying to build a simple TCP server. I've attached my code below. Whenever a client disconnects, it will be added to server.deadConns.

If I use a simple Client and keep connecting and disconnecting to the TCP Server (code below), the memory usage of my Golang app just keeps going up. If I then stop connecting and reconnecting my Client and wait, the memory usage will slowly start to go down. It takes a long time for it to go down but it will.

I noticed this issue when I was running my TCP server on Azure and the memory usage on the VM just kept going up until the machine crashed. I checked the logs and saw that there was some clients that just kept connecting and disconnecting all the time. I then tried it locally on my own machine and noticed that the same thing happens.

```
//NewTCPServer Creates the TCP Server
func NewTCPServer(port string, logger *logrus.Logger) *TCPServer {
    server := new(TCPServer)
    server.socketAPI = socketapi.NewSocketAPI(logger)
    newConns := make(chan net.Conn, 128)
    server.deadConns = make(chan net.Conn, 128)
    server.sessions = make(map[net.Conn]*types.ClientSession)
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000") + ": Listening to: " + port)
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+port)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    go func() {
        for {
            conn, err := listener.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000") + ": Connected: " + conn.RemoteAddr().String())
            newConns <- conn
        }
    }()

    go func(server *TCPServer) {
        for {
            select {
            case conn := <-newConns:
                session := new(types.ClientSession)
                tcp := createTCPSocket(&conn, server)
                session.Socket = tcp
                server.sessions[conn] = session
            case deadConn := <-server.deadConns:
                sess, ok := server.sessions[deadConn]

                if ok {
                    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000") + ": Found session")
                    if server.socketAPI.StopSubscriptionOnClose(sess) {
                        delete(server.sessions, deadConn)
                    }
                }

                fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000") + ": Delete session!")
                _ = deadConn.Close()
                sess.Socket = nil
                sess = nil
            }
        }
    }(server)
    return server
}
```

Comment: Probably you don't free some resources, which when the server left alone, eventually may time out (explains the slow memory reclamation). But when some clients do frequent connect / disconnect, the server memory is consumed at a quicker rate than it is being released thanks to timeouts. We can't tell based on the code sample you posted.

Comment: @icza I just found the error. I didn't close a channel in my TCP server code. Sorry about that, I'm new to Go.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the error. I didn't close a channel in my TCP server code.